# Copy and then remove files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to create a simple batch script which:

1. Copies all the files inside folder `A` to the current directory (which also contains some files)
2. Runs some commands
3. Remove all the copied files

An straight-forward solution is to loop through all the files inside `A`, copy them and keep a list of them. Then clean-up at the end.

But I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
copy "c:\A\*.*" .
rem run commands
for %%a in ("c:\a\*.*") do del "%%~nxa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Save a list of the files, copy them, do your stuff, then delete using your list:

```
dir /b A >list.txt
copy A\*.* .

rem do stuff here

for /F "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do del %%i
del list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "folder=%userprofile%\A"
set "dirlist=my dirlist.txt"

dir /b "%folder%" > "%dirlist%"
copy "%folder%"

rem doit here

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%dirlist%") do erase "%%~a"
```

It belongs to you to care for duplicate files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
attrib +R *.*
copy \A\*.*
rem run commands
del *.*
attrib -R *.*
```

Of course, this method works only if the commands does NOT modify anyone of the original files, but it is faster and also prevents to overwrite anyone of the original files.